# getPost funciona a veces sí y a veces no en Codeigniter 4.4.4

Tags: codeigniter, post

Tengo un sistema formado por una raspberry pi que envía datos de unos sensores a una web hecha con Codeigniter 4.4.4. Los datos se envían mediante post con código python.

El caso es que si envío los datos digamos, de uno en uno como en el ejemplo siguiente:

```py
    ruta_post = 'https://xxx...'
    
    datos = {
        'xidproyecto': 'eko', 
        'sensor': '10000-002',
        'dato': '65.56',
        'ndatos': '6',
        'dev': '0.03'
        }

    # Realizar la petición POST
    response = requests.post(ruta_post, data=datos)
```

Los puedo recoger con el código que muestro a continuación en CI4:

```
        $request = \Config\Services::request();
     
        $sensores = '';
        foreach ($request->getPost() as $key => $value) {
            $sensores .= 'Key: ' . $key . ' | Value: ' . $value;
        }
```

Nótese que aquí utilizo getPost() y funciona correctamente.

Sin embargo, si envío los datos en un json como el siguiente:

```
{'sensores': 
    [
    {'xidproyecto': 'eko'}, 
    {'sensor': '10000-003', 'dato': '61.02', 'ndatos': '6', 'dev': '0.39'}, 
    {'sensor': '10000-004', 'dato': '23.3', 'ndatos': '6', 'dev': '0.08'}, 
    {'sensor': '10000-005', 'dato': '53.35', 'ndatos': '6', 'dev': '1.09'}, 
    {'sensor': '10000-006', 'dato': '21.97', 'ndatos': '6', 'dev': '0.51'}, 
    {'sensor': '10000-007', 'dato': '43.18', 'ndatos': '6', 'dev': '3.06'}, 
    {'sensor': '10000-048', 'dato': '19.47', 'ndatos': '6', 'dev': '0.33'}
    ]
}
```

con getPost() no los recoge. Tengo que utilizar getVar:

```
        $request = \Config\Services::request();

        $sensores = '';

        $sensores = $request->getVar('sensores');
```

Y así funciona perfectamente.

En la documentación de CI4 se aconseja no utilizar getVar y utilizar en su lugar getPost o getGet pero el caso es que getPost() NO funciona en el segundo caso y no tiene sentido utilizar getGet() porque estoy haciendo una petición post.

¿Alguna explicación de por qué no funciona en el segundo caso y sí en el primero?

**Editado a petición de Excorpion**

Gracias por tu respuesta Excorpion.

Contestando a tu pregunta, envío el json desde un script en python (ojo con esto) con este código que he preparado para que veamos de forma sencilla lo que hago:

```
import requests

xidproyecto = 'eko'

#creamos un diccionario que contendrá todo
dicc_data= {}
#cada conjunto de datos son los datos de un sensor, pero el primer elemento es distinto, debe llevar el id del proyecto
dicc_data['sensores'] = [{'xidproyecto': xidproyecto}]

arreglo_dicc = {
    'sensor': '10000-001',
    'dato': '12.34',
    'ndatos': '9',
    'dev': '2.45'
}
    
#añadimos a la lista del diccionario
dicc_data['sensores'].append(arreglo_dicc)

#nuevo dato de sensor
arreglo_dicc = {
    'sensor': '10000-002',
    'dato': '64.34',
    'ndatos': '9',
    'dev': '1.35'
}

#añadimos a la lista del diccionario
dicc_data['sensores'].append(arreglo_dicc)

print(dicc_data)

url = "http://localhost/mclima2024/prueba_json"

try:
    # envío con post
    response = requests.post(url, json=dicc_data)

    # Verificar el estado de la respuesta
    if response.status_code == 200:
        print('La petición fue exitosa')
        print('Respuesta del servidor:', response.text)
        vjson = response.json()
    else:
        print('Error al hacer la petición:' + str(response.status_code))
    
except Exception:
    print('ERROR')
```

Lo que hago es crear un diccionario en python (dicc_data) y requests.post lo convierte a json y lo envía, según he leído en la documentación.

Con el código que sugieres:

```
$sensores = $request->getBody();
$data = json_decode($sensores, true);
die(json_encode($data));
```

Funciona perfectamente: la variable $sensores es un json (lo he comprobado al devolver $data).

Sin embargo, con mi código:

```
$sensores = $request->getVar('sensores');
```

obtengo un objeto, no un json, no hace falta hacer decode.

Y si cambio en mi código getVar por getPost no funciona, no recoge nada.

Comment: Gracias por la aclaración, contexto importante saber que viene desde python y está bien enviado. Ahora, que necesitas solucionar? Por que la documentación "no usar getVar en proyectos nuevos", además de otros motivos. Cómo necesitas procesar ese JSON tu ?

Comment: Todo funciona bien con getVar, pero la documentación de CI4 advierte claramente que no debe de usarse en proyectos nuevos. Cito textualmente: "Important. This method exists only for backward compatibility. Do not use it in new projects. Even if you are already using it, we recommend that you use another, more appropriate method." ¿Mejor usar getBody?

Comment: Claro, es exactamente lo que dice la documentación. Si con el ótro método, solucionas tu problema, creo que estaría todo solucionado. No veo el porqué usar getVar, cuando la misma documentación dice, "no usar".

Answer (score 0):

No me queda claro exactamente como estás enviando ese JSON, pero una búsqueda rápida me dió la siguiente información. (por favor edita tu publicación y al JSON agrega el código de cómo lo estás enviando)

1. En el controlador de CodeIgniter debes obtener el cuerpo de la solicitud, utilizando: `$request->getBody()`
2. Tengo entendido que un JSON no se puede enviar así sin más, y menos ser recibido de ese modo. Por lo que no veo en tu código un `json_encode` o un `json_decode`.

Voy a suponer que estás relizando un correcto envío del JSON, por lo que entonces para recibirlo, haremos lo siguiente:

```
$request = \Config\Services::request();
$jsonData = $request->getBody();
$data = json_decode($jsonData, true);
```

De este modo, `$data` contendrá tu información en un array asociativo.

Por otro lado, según la documentación, es buena idea que verifiques si la información recibida es un JSON, entre otras cosas, pero para eso, te dejaré anexada la documentación:
https://codeigniter4.github.io/CodeIgniter4/incoming/incomingrequest.html#determining-request-type